# how to get GET variable's value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

how can i get the get variable in javascript?

i want to pass it in jquery function.

```
function updateTabs(){

            //var number=$_GET['number']; how can i do this?
        alert(number);
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: number });

    }
```

Comment: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
var $_GET = {};
if(document.location.toString().indexOf('?') !== -1) {
    var query = document.location
                   .toString()
                   // get the query string
                   .replace(/^.*?\?/, '')
                   // and remove any existing hash string (thanks, @vrijdenker)
                   .replace(/#.*$/, '')
                   .split('&');

    for(var i=0, l=query.length; i<l; i++) {
       var aux = decodeURIComponent(query[i]).split('=');
       $_GET[aux[0]] = aux[1];
    }
}
//get the 'index' query parameter
alert($_GET['index']);
```

Comment: I think `unescape()` needs to be run at line 9 in your code. Apart from that, this is a good solution.

Comment: Much better to use decodeURIComponent for both: parameter name and parameter value.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (...index('?') !== -1)`? That's a big difference.

Comment: @phileaton you're right. I have no idea how did that slip and... how everyone else did the same until now. Thanks.

Comment: split('&'),
=>split('&');

Comment: +1 Aliaksei Nikuliak. This is much better:
`var aux = query[i].split('='); $_GET[decodeURIComponent(aux[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aux[1]);`

Comment: window.location is not set as expected when a JavaScript file is included in HTML using a SCRIPT tag. Any arguments are lost using this approach.

Answer (score 10):

Write:

```
var $_GET=[];
window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(a,name,value){$_GET[name]=value;});
```

Then `$_GET['number']`

Comment: Don't create variables in JS without `var`. I'd recommend avoiding starting variable names with `$` in JS, it isn't typical. Don't use arrays to hold key/value pairs, use plain objects for that.

Comment: @Quentin: The dollar-sign in front of variables is typically used as a convention for jquery objects. `var $rows = $("tr")` for example.

Comment: @JordanArseno — I never said it wasn't allowed by the standard, just that it wasn't *typical* for JavaScript.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
if (location.search != "")
{
    var x = location.search.substr(1).split(";")
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
         var y = x[i].split("=");
         alert("Key '" + y[0] + "' has the content '" + y[1]+"'")
    }
}
```