# Retrieving url parameter from one html to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending one variable through an html file to another but using the code bellow to the second file it does't grab the variable.

For example : From i am sending `myfile.html?myvariable=x`

and i am trying to grab it with the code bellow..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var myletter = Request.QueryString("myvariable");
alert (myletter);
});
</script>
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't grab the value". Is it bringing up the alert at all? Is there an error message?

Comment: You are mixing some some ASP JS code here: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049620/how-to-get-get-variables-value-in-javascript

Comment: or try this something like this: `<%=Request.QueryString("myvariable") %>`

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/url-parameters-jquery/

Comment: Alert doesn't works.. I don't get anything @ChrisHardie i want to retrieve the x value on the second page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanna to do it in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var match = (window || this).location.href.match(/\?(.*)$/);;
match = match ? match[1] : '';
alert(match.split("=")[1]);
</script>
```

njoy

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myletter = '<%=Request.QueryString("myvariable"); %>';
    alert (myletter);
});
</script>
```

With jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myletter = $.getUrlVar('myvariable');
    alert (myletter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and for every single other possible way of doing this in javascript: 
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)