# enter term into hidden form field with html and css possible?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have created a form in HTML/CSS on my website.

Now, my idea is to give out links that would contain some string (basically like an affiliate link) and would like that string to be entered in a hidden form field to be submitted, or somehow else, have that string in the submitted data.
is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: No, you need Javascript for that.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard, but it would required some JavaScript.

Comment: There seems to be an answer - below... using php or javascript - i was asking if there is a way....;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of approaching this, both of which use a `GET` variable in the link you distribute.

First off, let's assume that--for example's purpose--your special string is `abc123`. You would then distribute a link that follows the form `http://example.com/my/form/?affiliate=abc123`.

Assuming that, here are two solutions, one in PHP and another in Javascript.

---

### PHP Solution

This one is fairly easy, as long as you're just setting a hidden field.

```
<input type='hidden' name='affiliate' value='<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['affiliate'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>' />
```

*Update:* Added `htmlspecialchars()` call to escape any input, to prevent security issues with users setting the `GET` variable manually.

---

### Javascript Solution

#### HTML

```
<input type='hidden' id='affiliate-input' name='affiliate' />
```

#### Javascript

This solution relies on [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). If you want a pure JS solution, let me know.

```
var $_GET = {};

// When the page loads, set the input value
$(document).ready(function(){
    setupGetVariables();

    var affiliateId = $_GET["affiliate"];

    $("#affiliate-input").val(affiliateId);
});

function setupGetVariables()
{
    if(document.location.toString().indexOf('?') !== -1) {
        var query = document.location
                   .toString()
                   // get the query string
                   .replace(/^.*?\?/, '')
                   // and remove any existing hash string (thanks, @vrijdenker)
                   .replace(/#.*$/, '')
                   .split('&');

        for(var i=0, l=query.length; i<l; i++) {
           var aux = decodeURIComponent(query[i]).split('=');
           $_GET[aux[0]] = aux[1];
       }
    }
}
```

*The `setupGetVariables()` method was helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049620/how-to-get-get-variables-value-in-javascript).*

Comment: **Danger**: That PHP is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: The JavaScript isn't very good either, it fails to URL Decode the data.

Comment: Should I wrap it in `addSlashes()` then?

Comment: Hell no. `addslashes` is a terrible tool for escaping things that use slashes for escape sequences (which is what it is designed for), and HTML doesn't use slashes for escape sequences! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Comment: Yes, that should be safe.

Comment: @Quentin alright, thanks for the heads up. I also swapped out that Javascript for something that actually parses the URL. CSSTricks be distributing poor code :(

Comment: i am a bit confused by this conversation here now - so is the PHP version "dangerous" and the javascript version suggested? (i am not sure i can add javascript easily on just that single page...)

Comment: So, the current version of the PHP you see above is safe. I had previously posted a piece of PHP that was vulnerable to a certain type of attack.

Comment: ok i have implemented the php version but i can not receive that value - it outputs empty... how to debug best?

Comment: If the form is POSTing back to the server, you should be able to access it's value through `$_POST['affiliate'];`. You have to make sure that there is an affiliate GET variable set, though, ie, that your URL that you use to load the form contains `?affiliate=[some id]`